# Is it possible to pass the parameter value to another parameter inside the button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Currently, I am working on MVC, and it is my first time coding with this.

I have a parameter in a button that could pass a parameter to a controller. 
I wanted to pass it to another parameter of a button.

View:

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="button" value="account" id="account">ユーザ情報</button>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="button" value="svAccount" id="account">SV情報</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MaintenanceMenu(string button)
{
    ActionResult action = null;

    switch (button)
    {
        case "account":
            action = RedirectToAction("AccountList", "Account", new {@Bvalue="1"});
            break;
        case "svAccount":
            action = RedirectToAction("AccountList", "Account", new {@Bvalue = "5"});
            break;
        default:
            action = RedirectToAction("LogOut", "Login");
            break;
    }

    return action;
}
```

Now, I wanted to pass the value "5" or "1" if either of the buttons was clicked to this.

```
<button type="button" class="btn_userfrom" name="button" value="menu" id="btn_create" data-list-url="<%:Url.Action("AccountCreate", "Account", new { @ref_code = @Bvalue }) %>">新規登録</button>
```

Is that even possible?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AccountList(string Id, string Bvalue)
        {       

                UserData userData = Session["info"] as UserData;
                if (userData.RoleCode != "4")
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("LogOut", "Login");
                }

                BusinessLogicResult Result =
                    new AccountListSearchLogic().doProcess(new BusinessLogicInput() {
                        UserInfoData = userData,
                        BvalueAction = Bvalue  
                    });
            var UserList = Result[AccountListSearchLogic.KEY_OUT_USER_LIST] as List<AccountUserListView>;
            return View(UserList);
        }
```

Comment: You can do it with `<a>` tag also treated as button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right. Then you get your value 5 or 1 in AccountList Action, which returns page with final button. You can do what progrAmmar suggest like this.

**1. Way - Model -**
You pass model with value into view where you use it.

In Controller

```
 public ActionResult AccountList(string value)
 {
      return this.View(value);
 }
```

In View

```
 @model string
 <button type="button" class="btn_userfrom" data-list-url="<%:Url.Action("AccountCreate", "Account", new { @ref_code = Model }) %>" name="button" value="menu" id="btn_create" >新規登録</button>
```

**2. Way - ViewBag -** You create viewbag which you use in your page. Keep in mind that viewbag will survive only one request.

In Controller

```
 public ActionResult AccountList(string value)
 {
      ViewBag.Value = value;
      return this.View();
 }
```

In View

```
 <button type="button" class="btn_userfrom" data-list-url="<%:Url.Action("AccountCreate", "Account", new { @ref_code = ViewBag.Value }) %>" name="button" value="menu" id="btn_create" >新規登録</button>
```

> EDIT

I would recoment you to create ViewModel with your UserList and BValue for your page.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel(List<AccountUserListView> userList, String bValue)
    {
        this.UserList = userList;
        this.BValue = bValue;
    }

    public List<AccountUserListView> UserList;
    public String BValue;
}
```

And pass it into your View.

```
public ActionResult AccountList(string Id, string Bvalue)
{       
    UserData userData = Session["info"] as UserData;
    if (userData.RoleCode != "4")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("LogOut", "Login");
    }

    BusinessLogicResult Result = new AccountListSearchLogic().doProcess(
                                       new BusinessLogicInput() {
                                           UserInfoData = userData,
                                           BvalueAction = Bvalue  
                                       }
                                 );
    var UserList = Result[AccountListSearchLogic.KEY_OUT_USER_LIST] 
                         as List<AccountUserListView>;

    return View(new MyViewModel(UserList, Bvalue));
}
```

Something like this. And in view:

```
@model MyViewModel
<button type="button" class="btn_userfrom" data-list-url="<%:Url.Action("AccountCreate", "Account", new { @ref_code = Model.BValue }) %>" name="button" value="menu" id="btn_create" >新規登録</button>
```

Comment: How should I Implement that Controller on My Controller?

Comment: I will post my Controller Sir.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IEnumerable<AccountUserListView>' does not contain a definition for 'BValue' and no extension method 'BValue' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<AccountUserListView>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to change model declaration on top of the .cshtml page to match your new ViewModel.

Comment: `@model MyViewModel` This one sir? Where should i put this>?

Comment: Ok. I Get it Sir. Thank you. I will reply once I finished my project, Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sir. That will do it. :) God Bless :)

Comment: Glad to hear, Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways (may be three)

1. Make the Value part of the Model and post the model to the View so you can do:
   `<button type="button" class="btn_userfrom" name="button" value="menu" id="btn_create" data-list-url="<%:Url.Action("AccountCreate", "Account", new { @ref_code = Model.BValue}) %>">新規登録</button>`
2. Put the value in ViewBag and call it on the View.
   `<button type="button" class="btn_userfrom" name="button" value="menu" id="btn_create" data-list-url="<%:Url.Action("AccountCreate", "Account", new { @ref_code = ViewBag.BValue }) %>">新規登録</button>`
3. Put the value in ViewData and call in on the View.
   `<button type="button" class="btn_userfrom" name="button" value="menu" id="btn_create" data-list-url="<%:Url.Action("AccountCreate", "Account", new { @ref_code = ViewData["BValue"].ToString()}) %>">新規登録</button>`

Comment: it does not work, any of this sir. maybe i have some mistakes on my code. that's why it does'nt work. I forgot, that `@ref_code` is declared in this code `public ActionResult AccountCreate(string ref_code)`

Comment: the value of `Bvalue` is also declared in this  `public class BusinessLogicInput : Dictionary<String, Object>
    {
     public string BvalueAction { get; set; }
}`

Comment: Why is it a Dictionary?